# pyspark save json handling nulls for struct

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Using Pyspark and Spark 2.4, Python3 here. While writing the dataframe as json file, if the struct column is null I want it to be written as `{}` and if the struct field is null I want it as `""`. For example:

```py
    >>> df.printSchema()
    root
     |-- id: string (nullable = true)
     |-- child1: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |-- f_name: string (nullable = true)
     |    |-- l_name: string (nullable = true)
     |-- child2: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |-- f_name: string (nullable = true)
     |    |-- l_name: string (nullable = true)

     >>> df.show()
    +---+------------+------------+
    | id|      child1|      child2|
    +---+------------+------------+
    |123|[John, Matt]|[Paul, Matt]|
    |111|[Jack, null]|        null|
    |101|        null|        null|
    +---+------------+------------+
    df.fillna("").coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").format('json').save('/home/test')
```

**Result:**

```json
    {"id":"123","child1":{"f_name":"John","l_name":"Matt"},"child2":{"f_name":"Paul","l_name":"Matt"}}
    {"id":"111","child1":{"f_name":"jack","l_name":""}}
    {"id":"111"}
```

**Output Required:**

```json
    {"id":"123","child1":{"f_name":"John","l_name":"Matt"},"child2":{"f_name":"Paul","l_name":"Matt"}}
    {"id":"111","child1":{"f_name":"jack","l_name":""},"child2": {}}
    {"id":"111","child1":{},"child2": {}}
```

I tried some map and udf's but was not able to acheive what I need. Appreciate your help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Spark 3.x

If you pass option [`ignoreNullFields`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.json) into your code, you will have output like this. Not exactly an empty struct as you requested, but the schema is still correct.

```py
df.fillna("").coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").format('json').option('ignoreNullFields', False).save('/home/test')
```

```json
{"child1":{"f_name":"John","l_name":"Matt"},"child2":{"f_name":"Paul","l_name":"Matt"},"id":"123"}
{"child1":{"f_name":"Jack","l_name":null},"child2":null,"id":"111"}
{"child1":null,"child2":null,"id":"101"}
```

#### Spark 2.x

Since that option above does not exist, I figured there is a "dirty fix" for that, is mimicking the JSON structure and bypassing the null check. Again, the result is not exactly like you're asking for, but the schema is correct.

```py
(df
    .select(F.struct(
        F.col('id'),
        F.coalesce(F.col('child1'), F.struct(F.lit(None).alias('f_name'), F.lit(None).alias('l_name'))).alias('child1'),
        F.coalesce(F.col('child2'), F.struct(F.lit(None).alias('f_name'), F.lit(None).alias('l_name'))).alias('child2')
    ).alias('json'))
    .coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").format('json').save('/home/test')
)
```

```json
{"json":{"id":"123","child1":{"f_name":"John","l_name":"Matt"},"child2":{"f_name":"Paul","l_name":"Matt"}}}
{"json":{"id":"111","child1":{"f_name":"Jack"},"child2":{}}}
{"json":{"id":"101","child1":{},"child2":{}}}
```

Comment: Looks like ignoreNullFields is available only in Spark 3.0 and above.

Comment: you were right, I updated my answer with Spark 2.4 workaround